# Admin site uses default database in Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, admin

I have a project with several apps, each having its own database. I have a working `routers.py` to specify the correct database to use for each model. One of the app uses the `django-admin` subsite to manage its models.

This was all working fine in Django 1.5, but when moving to Django 1.6, I am not anymore able to edit my models: When I access the `edit` page of a model, I am getting an error "`[SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired`".

After some investigation, it seems like Django tries to connect to the database `default` which contains only dummy data in this project, as it should not be used anywhere.

Why does Django try to connect to the `default` database in 1.6, whereas it was working fine in 1.5? How can I fix this issue in 1.6?

[EDIT]

After some more research, I have found that Django uses the decorator `@transaction.atomic` for a few functions of its class `ModelAdmin`.

Looking at the code of this decorator, it seems like it's intended to support the possibility of specifying the database alias that needs to be used for this atomic transaction, with `@transaction.atomic(using)`, and otherwise, if just called with `@transaction.atomic` as it is in the `ModelAdmin` Django class, it will use the `DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS` defined in `django.db.utils`.

I have tried unsuccessfully to override this behaviour and make these functions use the database alias I want.

Would you know of any way to do this?

Comment: Consider asking on [irc #django](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/IrcFAQ)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#exposing-multiple-databases-in-django-s-admin-interface
Django’s admin doesn’t have any explicit support for multiple databases. If you want to provide an admin interface for a model on a database other than that specified by your router chain, you’ll need to write custom ModelAdmin classes that will direct the admin to use a specific database for content.

Comment: @StefanNch: The database router is enough and I use it. [Django docs about it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/multi-db/#exposing-multiple-databases-in-django-s-admin-interface): "If you want to provide an admin interface for a model on a database other than that specified by your router chain..."

Comment: The documentation explicitly says "other than that specified by your router chain". But I would like to use the one specified by my router chain, but the admin site doesn't let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a way to force Django admin to use the database I want, but it's really hacky. If someone comes with a better solution, please do post it.

I have created a file named admin_helper.py where I redefine the methods that use the `@transaction.atomic` decorator in Django codebase, with exactly the same content, and using the decorator `@transaction.atomic(DATABASE_ALIAS)` which tells Django to use the correct database:

```
DATABASE_ALIAS = 'alias_of_the_database_i_want_to_use'

class ModelAdminCustom(admin.ModelAdmin):
    @csrf_protect_m
    @transaction.atomic(DATABASE_ALIAS)
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        # exact same content as the method defined in django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin

    @csrf_protect_m
    @transaction.atomic(DATABASE_ALIAS)
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        # exact same content as the method defined in django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin

    @csrf_protect_m
    @transaction.atomic(DATABASE_ALIAS)
    def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        # exact same content as the method defined in django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin

class MultiDBUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    @sensitive_post_parameters_m
    @csrf_protect_m
    @transaction.atomic(DATABASE_ALIAS)
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        # exact same content as the method defined in django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin

# Unregister existing instance of UserAdmin for the User model, and register my own
try:
    admin.site.unregister(User)
finally:
    admin.site.register(User, MultiDBUserAdmin)
```

Then in my normal admin.py:

```
from myapp.admin_helper import ModelAdminCustom

class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdminCustom):
    pass

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```